# Which Java IDE created the project?

Tags: java, ide

How would one know which Java IDE created a Java project by looking at the files and folders?
Do most IDEs create the same project files such that any IDE (Eclipse, Intellij IDEA, NetBeans, etc) can open and execute without modification?

I have a project I've inherited and just want to figure out which tool it was created with.  Nothing more.

Comment: One would do some research or do some Google searches...

Comment: if you want interoperability use an "external" build system, like any, maven, gradle etc.

Comment: @jahroy: actually I did some google searches looking for this very information.  Found nothing indicating the differences in how IDEs create or manage projects, anything indicating that they're all the same or different, etc.  Perhaps instead of being snippy you'd suggest a search using different words that I as a java novice might not have considered.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Netbeans creates a folder called nbproject, you just need to try building a project with each.  Some IDEs don't put their project data inside the project, so they will be hard to detect.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  I mainly use Intellij, but I've never had a problem using a project another IDE created.  It requires a good understanding of the classpath and how to modify it in your IDE.

Comment: I would try downloading a few IDEs and checking out their project structure.

Comment: Apparently I don't know enough about Intellij IDEA.  When I open the .project file, everything is loaded into the IDE, but it must need more configuration before the Run button is enabled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to work independently from IDEs, use [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/). Most IDEs allow you to import Maven projects (after installing the necessary plugin), which will generate the correct project files for that IDE. Mostly such files shouldn't be added to source control, so use svn/git ignore on them.

If it has an .settings folder, it's eclipse, if it have a .idea folder, it's InteiJ Idea. But that doesn't matter, because you don't need them. Just create an empty java project in your favorite IDE (or use Maven as above) and drop the source code in it

Comment: I've actually inherited some source so trying to figure out which tool it was created with, but don't know how to easily tell, or if one should be able to tell by looking at the file/folder layout.

Comment: If it has an .settings folder, it's eclipse, if it have a .idea folder, it's InteiJ Idea. But that doesn't matter, because you don't need them. Just create an empty java project in your favorite IDE (or use Maven as above) and drop the source code in it.

Comment: @asgoth your comment is an answer, while your actual answer is the plus for the real answer.

Comment: Thanks this is what I needed.  Turns out I have neither a .settings or .idea folder, but on inspecting the .project file, it references <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name> in the buildSpec, so that answers the question.